# Can this C loop be optimized further?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction, sse, simd

I squealed out loud.
This really makes you wonder.

I dread to think what would happen if I chose 'Favor size over speed'.

Setting: Visual Studio 2010

```
<Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>
<IntrinsicFunctions>true</IntrinsicFunctions>
<FavorSizeOrSpeed>Speed</FavorSizeOrSpeed>
<EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>StreamingSIMDExtensions2</EnableEnhancedInstructionSet>
<FloatingPointModel>Precise</FloatingPointModel>
```

How does:

```
for (i = 0; i < some_num; i++)
{
    one += buf[i] * buf[i];     
    two += buf[i] * buf[off+i];
}
```

translate to this:

```
131:    for (i = 0; i < some_num; i++)
132:    {
133:        one += buf[i] * buf[i];
00404B40  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [eax-4]
00404B45  movss       xmm7,dword ptr [esp+18h]
00404B4B  movss       xmm2,dword ptr [eax]
00404B4F  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm2
00404B52  movss       xmm4,dword ptr [eax+4]
00404B57  cvtps2pd    xmm1,xmm0
00404B5A  mulsd       xmm3,xmm3
00404B5E  movss       xmm6,dword ptr [eax+8]
00404B63  mulsd       xmm1,xmm1
00404B67  cvtps2pd    xmm5,xmm4
00404B6A  mulsd       xmm5,xmm5
00404B6E  cvtps2pd    xmm7,xmm7
00404B71  addsd       xmm1,xmm7
00404B75  cvtpd2ps    xmm1,xmm1
00404B79  cvtss2sd    xmm1,xmm1
00404B7D  addsd       xmm1,xmm3
00404B81  xorps       xmm3,xmm3
00404B84  cvtpd2ps    xmm1,xmm1
00404B88  cvtss2sd    xmm1,xmm1
00404B8C  addsd       xmm1,xmm5
00404B90  cvtpd2ps    xmm1,xmm1
00404B94  cvtss2sd    xmm3,xmm1
   134:        two += buf[i] * buf[off+i];
00404B98  cvtps2pd    xmm0,xmm0
00404B9B  cvtps2pd    xmm2,xmm2
00404B9E  cvtps2pd    xmm1,xmm6
00404BA1  mulsd       xmm1,xmm1
00404BA5  addsd       xmm3,xmm1
00404BA9  xorps       xmm1,xmm1
00404BAC  cvtpd2ps    xmm1,xmm3
00404BB0  cvtps2pd    xmm5,xmm1
00404BB3  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [eax+0Ch]
00404BB8  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm1
00404BBB  mulsd       xmm3,xmm3
00404BBF  addsd       xmm5,xmm3
00404BC3  xorps       xmm3,xmm3
00404BC6  cvtpd2ps    xmm3,xmm5
00404BCA  cvtps2pd    xmm5,xmm3
00404BCD  movss       xmm3,dword ptr [eax+10h]
00404BD2  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm3
00404BD5  mulsd       xmm3,xmm3
00404BD9  addsd       xmm5,xmm3
00404BDD  xorps       xmm3,xmm3
00404BE0  cvtpd2ps    xmm3,xmm5
00404BE4  cvtps2pd    xmm5,xmm3
00404BE7  movss       xmm3,dword ptr [eax+14h]
00404BEC  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm3
00404BEF  mulsd       xmm3,xmm3
00404BF3  addsd       xmm5,xmm3
00404BF7  xorps       xmm3,xmm3
00404BFA  cvtpd2ps    xmm3,xmm5
00404BFE  cvtps2pd    xmm5,xmm3
00404C01  movss       xmm3,dword ptr [eax+18h]
00404C06  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm3
00404C09  mulsd       xmm3,xmm3
00404C0D  addsd       xmm5,xmm3
00404C11  xorps       xmm3,xmm3
00404C14  cvtpd2ps    xmm3,xmm5
00404C18  movss       dword ptr [esp+18h],xmm3
00404C1E  movss       xmm3,dword ptr [ecx-4]
00404C23  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm3
00404C26  mulsd       xmm3,xmm0
00404C2A  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [esp+10h]
00404C30  cvtps2pd    xmm0,xmm0
00404C33  addsd       xmm3,xmm0
00404C37  xorps       xmm0,xmm0
00404C3A  cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm3
00404C3E  movss       xmm3,dword ptr [ecx]
00404C42  cvtps2pd    xmm0,xmm0
00404C45  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm3
00404C48  mulsd       xmm2,xmm3
00404C4C  addsd       xmm0,xmm2
00404C50  movss       xmm2,dword ptr [ecx+4]
00404C55  cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm0
00404C59  cvtss2sd    xmm0,xmm0
00404C5D  cvtps2pd    xmm2,xmm2
00404C60  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm4
00404C63  mulsd       xmm2,xmm3
00404C67  addsd       xmm0,xmm2
00404C6B  movss       xmm2,dword ptr [ecx+8]
00404C70  cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm0
00404C74  cvtss2sd    xmm0,xmm0
00404C78  cvtps2pd    xmm2,xmm2
00404C7B  cvtps2pd    xmm1,xmm1
00404C7E  cvtps2pd    xmm3,xmm6
00404C81  mulsd       xmm2,xmm3
00404C85  addsd       xmm0,xmm2
00404C89  movss       xmm2,dword ptr [ecx+0Ch]
00404C8E  cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm0
00404C92  cvtss2sd    xmm0,xmm0
00404C96  cvtps2pd    xmm2,xmm2
00404C99  mulsd       xmm2,xmm1
00404C9D  addsd       xmm0,xmm2
00404CA1  cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm0
00404CA5  xorps       xmm1,xmm1
00404CA8  cvtss2sd    xmm1,xmm0
00404CAC  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [ecx+10h]
00404CB1  cvtps2pd    xmm2,xmm0
00404CB4  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [eax+10h]
00404CB9  cvtps2pd    xmm0,xmm0
00404CBC  mulsd       xmm2,xmm0
00404CC0  addsd       xmm1,xmm2
00404CC4  xorps       xmm0,xmm0
00404CC7  cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm1
00404CCB  add         eax,20h
00404CCE  add         ecx,20h
00404CD1  cvtps2pd    xmm1,xmm0
00404CD4  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [ecx-0Ch]
00404CD9  cvtps2pd    xmm2,xmm0
00404CDC  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [eax-0Ch]
00404CE1  cvtps2pd    xmm0,xmm0
00404CE4  mulsd       xmm2,xmm0
00404CE8  addsd       xmm1,xmm2
00404CEC  xorps       xmm0,xmm0
00404CEF  cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm1
00404CF3  xorps       xmm1,xmm1
00404CF6  cvtps2pd    xmm1,xmm0
00404CF9  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [ecx-8]
00404CFE  xorps       xmm2,xmm2
00404D01  cvtps2pd    xmm2,xmm0
00404D04  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [eax-8]
00404D09  cvtps2pd    xmm0,xmm0
00404D0C  mulsd       xmm2,xmm0
00404D10  addsd       xmm1,xmm2
00404D14  xorps       xmm0,xmm0
00404D17  cvtpd2ps    xmm0,xmm1
00404D1B  movss       dword ptr [esp+10h],xmm0
00404D21  cmp         eax,offset buf+84h (42D6A4h)
00404D26  jl          gem+290h (404B40h)
   135:    }
```

Comment: Just FYI, under some circumstances optimizing for "size" is actually faster than for "speed" due to memory / cache effects.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to take those effects into consideration when it optimizes for "speed"?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Well how would VC++ know your cache size or available memory at runtime? I assume it still makes some guesses, but those can hardly be perfect without further information.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is yes. Visual Studio does not currently vectorize code. If you look at the assembly, those are all scalar SSE instructions. And your loop is clearly vectorizable.

You will have to use a vectorizing compiler to get better results. Or emit the vector-SSE instructions yourself using intrinsics.

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_bk_intro.htm

Another thing you could try is:

Change the floating-point mode to "fast" instead of "precise". The compiler is promoting the intermediates to double-precision and converting them back - which adds a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're mixing single and double precision types in your expressions, which results in a lot of unnecessary conversions. If you fix this then the code should be smaller and more efficient.

Also you could use a better compiler, such as Intel's ICC, which may well be able to vectorize this loop as @Mysticial has already suggested.

One further point - I haven't studied the code too closely but it looks like the loop has been unrolled, so it may be in fact somewhat more efficient than it at first appears.

Comment: Actually, it looks like all the variables are single-precision. But because the floating-point mode is "precise", all the intermediates are promoted to double-precision and then converted back to single-precision.

Comment: @Mysticial: yes, you're probably right - it's a pity the OP didn't include the declarations of `buf`, `one`, `two`.

Comment: Uh, sorry about that. All of those are 32-bit floats. though the mac-like (+*) lines tend to compile into 80-bit precision, I believe. Thanks for the suggestions. I got the code down to a somewhat satisfying performance by separating it into a function and moving the indexing before the MAC's and offseting stuff before the loop.

Comment: I can't use vectorization for the second half of the loop, since I'm pretty sure 'off' is not always divisible by four. I'm afraid to separate it into two loops because of probable pipeline stalling (still don't know how to predict/calculate/prevent this). Will try anyway.

Comment: Nope. Separating did not work. I got some 25% (in milliseconds) overhead by doing that.

Comment: If you can't align the data, there are two options: 1. Use unaligned loads. They are slower, but can be a quick fix. 2. Buffer the loads. Load them in aligned quantities and then shuffle them into the final vector that you want. (This second approach tends to be the fastest, but also the messiest.)

Answer (score 2):

Note this:

```
00404CCB  add         eax,20h
00404CCE  add         ecx,20h
```

The loop has been unrolled to work on 8 `i` values at a time.

Comment: Ah of course, this explains the massive number of instructions.